# How to uninstall a unnecessary installed bluetooth driver (rtbth)?

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, bluetooth

My bluetooth had a problem, so I searched in this site about how to fix it. One of the answers showed the following instructions:

```
sudo apt install blueman

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
```

```
sudo vim /etc/modules
```

Comment all and add this line

```
rtbth
```

Reboot and open

```
sudo blueman-manager
```

**If still not work, try this**

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sleep 1
sudo modprobe btusb
```

I followed the first instruction, it did not worked. I tried the second one and it worked flawless, as the second worked independently of the first, I want to undo the changes done by the first without any issues.

Here are information about the driver:

```
Package: rtbth-dkms
Version: 3.9.6~git20200303-1~focal1
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Maintainer: blaze <blaze@vivaldi.net>
Installed-Size: 1.430 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), dkms (>= 2.1.0.0)
Recommends: bluez
Suggests: pm-utils
Download-Size: 316 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
Description: Bluetooth driver for RT3290 Wireless
 DKMS package of Bluetooth driver for RT3290 Wireless cards
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ppa-purge: `sudo apt install ppa-purge`
2. Purge the repository and everything installed from it: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms`

Comment: And what about the edited etc/modules? I have to do anything?